# Как использовать сообщения в unicode в assert-методах?

Tags: python, кодировка, юнит-тесты, unicode

Не могу добиться, чтобы методы `assert` корректно выводили сообщения в юникоде:

```
# coding=utf-8
from unittest import TestCase

class Example(TestCase):

    def test_mcve(self):
        message = u'Привет, мир!'
        print message
        self.assertTrue(False, message)
```

Результат выполнения:

```
Testing started at 17:07 ...
Привет, мир!

Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/n.volynkin/example/mcve.py", line 9, in test_mcve
    self.assertTrue(False, message)
AssertionError: \u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442, \u043c\u0438\u0440!
```

То есть просто так строка корректно выводится в stdout, а из ассерта - ломается юникод. Как получить нормальные строки?

Comment: Надо было переходить на третий питон)

Comment: @andreymal возможно сам я писал бы сразу на третьем, но это рабочий код, его уже есть сколько-то тысяч строк и переписывать просто ради новой версии нецелесообразно )

Answer (score 3):

Совершенно неожиданно я нашёл ответ:

```
class Example(TestCase):
    def test_mcve(self):
        message = u'Привет, мир!'
        print message
        self.assertTrue(False, message.encode('utf-8'))
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14181711/2790048

Когда пойму магию юникода в Python, дополню ответ.